# @Keep annotation and keep rules are not working for interfaces nested inside classes or other interfaces by enabling Android R8 obfuscation

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8, android-obfuscation

I am using Android R8 obfuscation in my Android library.
After including the AAR file in the application module of the library's client project, I am getting compile time errors for interfaces that are declared inside the class or another interface.

e.g. one of the public interfaces is MyPublicInterface:

```
interface InterfaceA {
    fun a()
}

interface InterfaceB {
    fun b()
}

class ClassA {
    interface NestedInterfaceOfA {
        fun nia()
    }
}

interface MyPublicInterface : InterfaceA, InterfaceB, ClassA.NestedInterfaceOfA
```

The interface `MyPublicInterface` is used by the application module.

I am getting the below errors while compiling the application module:

```
"Cannot access ClassA$NestedInterfaceOfA which is a supertype of MyPublicInterface. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath."
"unresolved supertypes ClassA$NestedInterfaceOfA"
```

I tried all the below rules:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers public interface * {
*;
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames public interface * {
*;
}
-keep public interface *$* {
*;
}
-keepclasseswithmembers public interface *$* {
*;
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames public interface *$* {
*;
}
-keepattributes InnerClasses, Signature
```

I tried by explicitly adding @Keep annotation in code and by explicitly adding the keep rule for a particular interface as well. But it didn't work.

**Note:** The entire code of the library is in Kotlin.

Comment: Proguard obfuscation is working fine with above rules. If the interfaces are moved out of classes/interfaces into separate files, it is working fine with R8 as well. As the codebase is having many more inner/nested interfaces, it is difficult to move them out of parent classes. We want to just do the migration from Proguard to R8.

Comment: This looks like a bug in R8. Could you open an issue on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788? Please include as much information as possible including the version of Android Studio you are using.

Answer (score -1):

The above specified issue is resolved now.
I used below solution for it:

Android studio version: `4.1.x`

Android tools version:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'` (Issue was occurring with version `4.0.2`)

Gradle version: `6.5.1` (Issue was occurring with version `6.3`)